# Can you use a BroadcastReceiver inside a method?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Is it possible to manager the lifecycle of BroadcastReceiver inside a method.

```
void handleSomething() {
    doSomethingThatWillBroadcast();
    BroadcastReceiver somethingReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (!intent.getBooleanExtra(SOMETHING_RESULT, false)) {
                finishSomething(false);
            } else {
                doAnotherSomethingThatWillBroadcast();
                BroadcastReceiver anotherSomethingReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        finishAnotherSomething();
                    }
                };
                IntentFilter anotherSomethingFilter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_SOMETHING);
                anotherSomethingFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                registerReceiver(anotherSomethingReceiver, anotherSomethingFilter);
            }
        }
    };

    IntentFilter somethingFilter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_APK);
    somethingFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    registerReceiver(somethingReceiver, somethingFilter);
}
```

I try to use this in an IntentService method but I get unregister errors all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

it's live while process live. Why don't just do

```
return somethingReceiver;
```

And then manage it where you want? My apps creates recievers in different class. Code same as yours, but with

```
return somethingReceiver;
```

and with Context in params.

```
BroadcastReciever handleSomething(Context context)
{
}
```

Then don't forget call

```
unregisterReciever();
```

when it needed.

---

> I try to use this in an IntentService method but I get unregister
>   errors all over the place.

I see same errors before. When I run unregisterReciever() on created recievers errors gone.
Your code create recievers, but don't have a way for unregister created recievers.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're talking about.

Comment: @JoshElias, maybe I don't clearly understand what you really want.

Comment: @JoshElias, edit answer. Do unregisterReciever(somethingReceiver);